# Matching strings containing 'and' in different languages and ampersands

Tags: python, pandas, string, join, nlp

Suppose that in 2 different data frames `df1`, `df2` I have 2 columns

```
df1['film'] = pd.Series(['Beavis & Butthead', 'Bonnie e Clyde', 'Adam & Eve'])
df2['film'] = pd.Series(['Beavis und Butthead', 'Bonnie & Clyde', 'Adam et Eve'])
```

of film titles in multiple different languages. (In reality my columns are much larger than this and don't exclusively contain titles with ampersands or different languages' equivalents of the word 'the'. Hence I cannot use something like stopwords for my problem, as it would amends these titles in too 'destructive' a way.)

None of these records result in matches when merging the data frames on these 2 columns, and they would still not all match if I did a simple `str.replace` since there is no way of knowing from any of the titles whether the ampersand should be 'e', 'et', 'und', 'and', etc.

Since I do not have a list of all the languages that the film titles are written in, how do I approach this problem?

Comment: That seems difficult to generalize, for example the words "and" in Finish ("ja") or in Latvian ("un") have a different meanings in other languages.